# Is it possible to delete a file with Firefox add-ons?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I know it's possible to make a Firefox add-on that can create, read, and write files, but is it possible to create an add-on that can delete a file after reading it?

Comment: I don't know what commands I would use to remove the file. The Mozilla I/O pages I could find said how to write and create files/folders, but nothing about deleting them. Some more googling, and getting past all the "How to Remove Add-ons" yields the nsIFile remove method, so I guess that solves the problem.

Comment: Don't worry man you don't have to show effort. Getting started is the hardest part so just ignore him. I would down vote him if I could down  vote comments.

Comment: @Noitidart - touche, I was being somewhat unproductive with that

Comment: No problem man, it's just that we all know getting started on something new is really hard if you don't have experience. Thanks for removing the downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, either using [`nsIFile.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFile#remove%28%29) or [`OS.File.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread#OS.File.remove%28%29) or the SDK's [`"io/file".remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file#remove%28path%29).

Comment: Thanks nameir for helping it out. I don't like to see others tell others to just give it a shot. Sometimes people need guidance to get started, that's actually the hardest part unless you are very experienced.